# In JavaScript is call() synchronous, and apply() asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to intercept function client-side function calls, and I have written this script to override the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open function. However, using call() breaks fetch requests in Chrome! The reason given-

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

When I replace the function call() with apply(), the warning goes away and the requests work again.

Original:

```
!(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    // dostuff
    open.call(this, method, newURL, async, user, password);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

New (working):

```
!(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    // dostuff
    open.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Although the code works - I am worried that this does not change the underlying problem. When the fetch spec catches up, it may break the intercept functionality again. Does anyone know if there is truly a sync vs async difference in call() vs apply()?

Comment: `call` and `apply` are both synchronous. The only difference between them is whether you provide arguments as an single array parameter, or as a comma separated series of parameters.

Comment: `deprecated` means just that, it doesn't mean it won't work now, but might not work in the future.  So all you have maybe done is hide a warning about it.  In the future when the `deprecated` becomes final, I assume both will fail.

Comment: You’re probably just screwing up the order of the arguments somehow, and/or there’s some issue with using the keyword `async`.